# SSRS convert decimal seconds to hh:mm:ss

Tags: reporting-services, time

I am trying to do an average call time calcualtion in SSRS at different group levels. I'm using the formula below to calculate averages for `IBTOTALTALK`, `IBTOTALHOLD`, `IBTOTALWRAP`.

```
=Iif(IsNothing(SUM(Fields!CALLS_HANDLED.Value))="True",0,
 Iif(SUM(Fields!CALLS_HANDLED.Value)=0,0,
 Format(DateAdd("s",Sum(Fields!IBTOTALTALK.Value) / Sum(Fields!CALLS_HANDLED.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")))
```

I then calculate an overall Call Handle TIme using this formula:

```
=Iif(IsNothing(SUM(Fields!CALLS_HANDLED.Value))="True",0,
 Iif(SUM(Fields!CALLS_HANDLED.Value)=0,0,
 Format(DateAdd("s",(Sum(Fields!IBTOTALTALK.Value)+Sum(Fields!IBTOTALHOLD.Value)+Sum(Fields!IBTOTALWRAP.Value))
 / Sum(Fields!CALLS_HANDLED.Value), "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")))
```

When I export the results to Excel, the Call Handle Time value is correct, but if you try to add up the three averages in Excel, it is off by 2-3 seconds, and the client wants it to be exact. It appears that the values are exported as or converted to integer in Excel.

CORRECT VALUES

```
AVG TALK               AVG HOLD            AVG WRAP            AVG CHT
 416.706522      36.489130   43.032609   496.228261 
 0:06:57               0:00:36            0:00:43              0:08:16
```

WHAT IS DISPLAYED

```
AVG TALK               AVG HOLD            AVG WRAP            SUM TOTAL
  416              36              43              495 
  0:06:56              0:00:36             0:00:43             0:08:15
```

Is there any way to export a more precise time value so that they add up to the correct result in Excel? I've tried a number of different time calculation formulas in SSRS and the one above delivers the most consistent result without producing an #ERROR message under certain conditions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which SSRS version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The DateAdd function does not round for you and it looks like you want to round up from milliseconds to seconds.
Use the round function ..

`format(dateadd("s", Round(Fields!IBTOTALTALK.Value / Fields!CALLS_HANDLED.Value, 0, system.MidpointRounding.ToEven) , "00:00:00"), "HH:mm:ss")`